# Validar DatePicker Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-datepicker

Estoy validando mi formulario con [formvalidation](/questions/tagged/formvalidation), la fecha solo se valida si la escribo, si la escojo desde el calendario no la válida. Si me pueden ayudar a validarla agradecería su ayuda. Utilizo el [datepicker](/questions/tagged/datepicker) de Jquery.

Campo formulario:

```
<div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="fechaEntrega">Fecha entrega</label>
                    <div class="col-md-4"> 
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon fa fa-calendar"></span>
                            <input type="text" id="fechaEntrega" name="fechaEntrega" class="form-control"></input>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Validación:

```
$().ready(function () {
$('#formularioSolicitudPedido').formValidation({// Validación datos capa cliente. TENER PRESENTE EL ID DEL FORM
    err: {container: 'tooltip'}, //muestra en tooltips
    icon: {valid: 'fa fa-thumbs-up', invalid: 'fa fa-thumbs-down', validating: 'fa fa-refresh'}, //iconos
    //locale: 'es_ES', //idioma - debe enlazar el archivo "es_ES.js"
    fields: {

        fechaEntrega: {
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'La fecha de entrega es requerida'
                }
            }
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: ¿No utilizas ningún framework para facilitar tu labor con JSF como PrimeFaces u OmniFaces?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza No, ninguno.

Comment: @LinaCortés prueba estableciendo la propiedad `name` solamente; tal vez, ya que las propiedades `id` y `name` tienen el mismo nombre, pueden generar ambigüedad. En este [enlace](http://formvalidation.io/examples/jquery-ui-datepicker/) se muestra un campo de fecha con la propiedad `name` establecida.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto te puede servir:

```
$('#formularioSolicitudPedido').formValidation({// Validación datos capa cliente. TENER PRESENTE EL ID DEL FORM
    err: {container: 'tooltip'}, //muestra en tooltips
    icon: {valid: 'fa fa-thumbs-up', invalid: 'fa fa-thumbs-down', validating: 'fa fa-refresh'}, //iconos
    //locale: 'es_ES', //idioma - debe enlazar el archivo "es_ES.js"
    fields: {

        fechaEntrega: {
            validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'La fecha es requerida'
                    },
                    date: {
                        format: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
                        message: 'La fecha no es valida'
                    }
                }
        }

    }
}).find('[name="fechaEntrega"]')
        .datepicker({
            onSelect: function(date, inst) {
                // Revalida el campo cuando se usa el picker
                $('#formularioSolicitudPedido').formValidation('revalidateField', 'fechaEntrega');
            }
        });
```